# WinForms designer for linux

Tags: c#, linux, winforms

Is there a WinForms C# designer for Linux? I have come across this [mwf-designer](https://github.com/mono/mwf-designer), but it is incomplete and very outdated.

Anyone know of anything up to date?

Comment: Mono/Xamarin shifted their focus on cross platform approaches like Xamarin.Forms, so WinForms attempt stopped a long while ago, and so should you. https://blog.xamarin.com/glimpse-future-xamarin-forms-3-0/ Of course, if you are interested in reviving that designer for Linux, you can do whatever you like with that code.

Comment: @LexLi Wasn't aware of that. I'm only new to the C# world. So developing with xamarin.forms I get multiplatform support, great! Is monodevelop, or something else going to have a gui designer for Linux?

Comment: The various Linux distributions make it difficult to support a visual designer for Xamarin.Forms. So far, you can only use Visual Studio on Windows or Visual Studio for Mac on macOS. Whether there would be Visual Studio for Linux is yet unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) is a Visual Studio equivalent for Linux, compatible with Visual Basic and C# code, a great thing for a beginner Ubuntu user that was a .Net programmer on Windows. Eclipse IDE is also a great and very powerful programming tool also compatible with C#.

[Download IDE from here](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/)

[image]

[image]

References:

http://www.monodevelop.com

https://askubuntu.com/questions/112135/is-there-an-ide-and-compiler-for-c-in-ubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/is-there-a-visual-studio-style-tool-ide

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski see this link : http://www.monodevelop.com/screenshots/  It has designer and tools to drag & drop like visual studio.

Comment: That visual designer you are referring to is for Gtk# only (as mentioned in the [Feature List](http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/feature-list/#visual-design))

Comment: I was specifically asking for WinForms, not Gtk#

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski In that case you have to make widgets with codes.